# Problems upgrading Rails 4.0.0 to 4.0.x (4.0.13) - private method `include' called for ActionDispatch::Assertions:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, webrick, rails-4-upgrade

I could not find a "direct" answer to this anywhere. Since I know there will be many other "Late Upgraders" to the party, I feel I need to get this out.

I had a Rails 4.0.0 app running Ruby 2.0.0-p247. After upgrading to 4.0.13, I ran into this error:

```
private method `include' called for ActionDispatch::Assertions:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I received this through rspec and WEBrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution via another issue from [layer-ruby](https://github.com/benedikt/layer-ruby/issues/7): [NoMethodError: private method `include' called for #-Class:#-Layer::RelationProxy:0x007fd1f67016e0--](https://github.com/benedikt/layer-ruby/issues/7#issuecomment-136739841)

[geoffreymm](https://github.com/geoffreymm) discovered that install Ruby 2.2.0 Fixed the issue.

I installed Ruby 2.2.5, and it did indeed solve the issue for me.

Comment: I didn't think it was right to do that, but ok I will. Thanks!